# How to add ArcObjects SDK into Visual Studio Express 2013?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, visual-studio, arcobjects

I have just installed the ESRI SDK from the 10.0 installation Disk and downloaded the Visual Studio Express 2013 and I'm trying to work through the ESRI Walkthrough named "Building custom UI elements using add-ins".   (  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/ )

I am looking forward to using this new Add-in format of customization, but am struggling to overcome the transition from the easy to use VBA Editor to the visual studio IDE.

My hurdle right now is in the walkthough it shows templates in the 'new project' dialog for ArcGIS and various options for ArcMap Add-In and such.  In the Visual Studio Express  dialog these options aren't showing up.  I guess I was expecting that when the SDK was installed they would show up here.  Can anyone direct me on how to get those comparable templates to show up in Visual Studio Express 2103?

Here is a screenshot showing the differences ( red arrow of the ESRI templates, and blue circle of my current options through VSE2013)

[image]

Comment: Last I checked you need VS express 2008 or VS 2010 for templates. Someone correct me on this.

Comment: @Sleep6 Very true. http://help.arcgis.com/en/systemrequirements/0151/01510000006n000000.htm

Answer (score 3):

The latest supported version is VS Express 2010. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000

Comment: Thank you for this step.  I have uninstalled the previous thing I had and installed this version of VS Express, but these templates are still not showing up.  Am I silly to think they might show up automatically?  I'm guessing there is some step of pointing the IDE to the SDK so it knows to look at it, but I'm obviously missing a step.  Do I need to re-install the SDK now that I have the proper VS?

Comment: You need to reinstall your SDK. Arc install will put the templates for the particular version in the right spot. Installation of the SDK must follow the installation of the IDE.

Comment: Yes. I am surprised you were able to instal the SDK. Normally it requires VS 2008 or 2010 installed otherwise it will not let you instal it. Please note that in version 10.2.1 you can target .Net 4 but in any version prior you still need to target .Net 3.5.  Some people were succesful targeting .Net 4 in earlier versions but it was not supported officially until the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically due to installing the new version of Visual Studio after ArcGIS 10.3. The easiest way to correct this is to run your ArcObjects SDK installer then select Modify and turn on the option to install the VisualStudio 2013 SDK:
[image: Install option]